# Как подключить JDBC драйвер в Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Начал изучать SQl, в качестве подопытной СУБД выбрал PostgreSQL. В процессе подготовки выявилась одна проблема - не пойму как подключить драйвер, программа ни как не хочет увидеть его класс, хотя в драйвере он лежит. Библиотеку драйвера импортировал, в модулях поставил галочку над Export, а работать все-равно не хочет. Драйвер скачивал с офф. сайта, версия 41 так как вроде написано что она под Java 8. **Помогите разобраться куда надо ткнуть чтобы оно заработало, не зря же я книги покупал. :(**

Для проверки работа-способности использую следующий код:

```
public class Eye {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.posgresql.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loading success!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

После компиляции выдает следующее:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.posgresql.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
at Eye.main(Eye.java:8)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

не posgresql, а postgresql! Что же вы сразу на форумы, вместо того, чтобы внимательно посмотреть на собственный код.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>  - > libraries (слева) нажать + и добавить .jar файл c драйвером.